# Maximum key length warning on a filtered index, but the actual key will always be smaller because of the filter - is this safe?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, indexing, query-optimization

I am optimizing a query in SQL Server 2019. It is a data lookup for a very large table which involves returning a lot of data, so I am creating a custom index for it.

Here is the index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_DataValues_FilteredEndVSNullDesc2
ON [dbo].[DataValues] (
    [EndTime] ASC,
    [ValueString] ASC, 
    [DomainId] ASC,
    [FieldType] ASC,
    [StartTime] DESC
)
INCLUDE ([Id],[ValueNumber])
WHERE ([EndTime] IS NULL AND [ValueString] IS NULL);
```

Each row in the database table must have *one* of a ValueNumber (`float`) or a ValueString (`nvarchar(4000)`). The other value will be NULL. Each row must also have a StartTime (`datetimeoffset(7)`), and *may* have an EndTime (also `datetimeoffset(7)`). If a row has no EndTime, it will be NULL.

For this particular query, I know the data I'm looking up will have ValueNumber set and ValueString NULL. I also know it's of a type where it won't have an EndTime - thus the index filter.

The problem I'm running into is that when I create the index, MSSQL warns:

`Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'UQ_DataValues_FilteredEndVSNull' has maximum length of 8028 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.`

Which, all right, I *did* put the ValueString in the index key. But:

- Because of the filter, I know the ValueString will always be NULL.
- If I don't put ValueString (or EndTime) in the key, the query optimizer will do a clustered index scan for it instead when I do the lookup, even though it exactly matches the filter predicate for the index (even when I use an index hint). This is significantly less efficient.

My question is: is this *safe?* Data with a ValueString will be added to the table, but it won't be added to the index, so this particular key formulation won't actually cause any insert/update failures - will it?

EDIT: I've been asked to include the sample query. Here is roughly what it would look like. Entity Framework will generate the query in the actual lookup, but it'd be something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP (5000000) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[FieldType] AS [FieldType], 
    [Project1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
    [Project1].[ValueNumber] AS [ValueNumber], 
    [Project1].[DomainId] AS [DomainId]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[DomainId] AS [DomainId], 
        [Extent1].[FieldType] AS [FieldType], 
        [Extent1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
        [Extent1].[ValueNumber] AS [ValueNumber]
        FROM [dbo].[DataValues] AS [Extent1] --WITH (INDEX(UQ_DataValues_FilteredEndVSNullDesc2)) , ideally
        WHERE ([Extent1].[EndTime] IS NULL) AND 
          ([Extent1].[ValueString] IS NULL) AND 
          ([Extent1].[StartTime] >= '01/01/2023') AND 
          ([Extent1].[StartTime] <= '10/26/2023') AND 
          ([Extent1].[DomainId] IN (1000003592, 1000003594, 1000003596, 1000003595, 1000004919, 1000004922, 1000004920, 1000004921, 1000003565, 1000003564, 1000003563, 1000003562, 1000004876, 1000004877, 1000004878, 1000004879, 1000003517, 1000003516, 1000003519, 1000003518, 1000003822, 1000003823, 1000003824, 1000003825, 1000003962, 1000003968, 1000003967, 1000003970)) AND 
          ([Extent1].[FieldType] IN (1))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Start] DESC
```

This query takes 1 minute with the existing index (not the one shown above), which does not include ValueNumber or ValueString. When I use the index shown above, including ValueString and EndTime in the key, the time drops to 50 seconds. If I don't include ValueString and EndTime in the key, I get no benefit compared to the existing index.

Note that the query is a toy version of the real query, which takes 10 minutes (!) with the existing index. I'd like to get it as fast as I possibly can.

Comment: Why are you including EndTime and Valuestring when values are always NULL?

Comment: Because if I don't, the query optimizer will do a separate clustered index scan for them (as I mentioned above). To get the query optimizer to _only_ rely on this index (which gives the most speed), I need to include both columns.

Comment: @SoItBegins That sounds like the query in question is doing a SELECT * instead of specifying the columns it needs.

Comment: Can you include the actual query. A filtered index will only be used if the optimizer can guarantee it will always cover all qualifying rows. If the columns you're filtering on can never both be null then clearly your filter clause is incorrect - you want one, or the other to be null.

Comment: OK, updated it.

Comment: For your filtered index to be used your where clause should match - and it doesn't, SQL Server cannot know if the other query criteria would be met correctly or not so it cannot use the index.

Comment: My WHERE clause does match, though. The index has WHERE EndTime IS NULL AND ValueString IS NULL, and so does the query's WHERE (with a number of other conditions). I had assumed the query optimizer would be able to realize that the query's WHERE was a subset of the index's WHERE. Is this not the case?

Comment: Also it's an EF query so I'm *guessing* things like the date range values are parameterized? SQL Server [doesn't use a filtered index for paramterized queries](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/filtered-indexes-and-dynamic-sql/).

Comment: Yes, queries are always parameterized in EF. However, the only parameters in the original query are the Start dates. `EndTime IS NULL` is not parameterized (and `ValueString IS NULL` won't be, either). So the query optimizer should still be able to detect it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255771/discussion-between-soitbegins-and-stu).